# The same code renders differently on different PCs

Tags: c, rendering, quaternions, glm-math, euler-angles

I have this weird problem while running the same OpenGL code on different computers. I'm rolling camera along the z axis (like a head tilt to either side) and on one PC it rotates normally (just rotates and the texture stays the same width and length). On the other PC, the same rotation causes the texture to expand (the bigger the roll angle the wider the texture). I don't know how to explain that better so [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VoA-e7ehOB1ZxgW3JE3x1KdWCpqoOrDi?usp=sharing) is the link to my google drive with a couple of videos.

Basically what I do is: use cglm to calculate Model, View and Projection (MVP) matrices from camera fov and camera resulting quaternions I calculate using cglm and provide those matrices to the vertex shader. Yet, the same code works differently on different PCs.

Here is a function I use to simulate those rotations.

```
void *fake_headtracking(void *c_ptr){
my_camera_t *c = c_ptr;
versor rollQuat, pitchQuat, yawQuat;

glm_quat_identity(rollQuat);
glm_quat_identity(yawQuat);
glm_quat_identity(pitchQuat);
float yaw, pitch, roll;
yaw = 180;
pitch = 0;
roll = 0;
float yawd = 1;
float pitchd = 1;
float rolld = -1;
while(!EXIT){
    // yaw += yawd;
    // pitch += pitchd;
    roll += rolld;
    if (roll >= 50 || roll <=-50) rolld = -rolld;
    if (pitch >= 50 || pitch <=-50) pitchd = -pitchd;
    if (yaw >= 50 || yaw <=-50) yawd = -yawd;
    glm_quatv(pitchQuat, my_radians(pitch), (vec3){1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});
    glm_quatv(yawQuat, my_radians(yaw), (vec3){0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f});
    glm_quatv(rollQuat, my_radians(roll), (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});
    glm_quat_mul(yawQuat, pitchQuat, c->resultQuat);
    glm_quat_mul(c->resultQuat, rollQuat, c->resultQuat);
    usleep(15000);
}

return NULL;
```

Here is what I do before rendering...

```
    // generate projection matrix
    glm_perspective(cam.fov, (GLfloat)SCR_WIDTH / (GLfloat)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.01f, 100.0f, proj); // zoom

    // generate view matrix
    glm_quat_look(cam.cameraPos, cam.resultQuat, view);

    // send MVP matrices to vertex shader
    my_send_shander_4x4_matrix(modelLoc, 1, &model[0][0]); 
    my_send_shander_4x4_matrix(viewLoc, 1, &view[0][0]); 
    my_send_shander_4x4_matrix(projLoc, 1, &proj[0][0]);  
        
    my_bind_texture(textures[0]); 
    my_bind_vertex_object_and_draw_it(VAOs[0], GL_TRIANGLES, myWin.numTriangles);
```

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
out vec2 TexCoord;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;
void main(){
   gl_Position = proj*view*model*vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z , 1.0);
   TexCoord = vec2(1.0 - aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/FilipVuk123/tmp_repo/tree/master/HT_testing/src) is a link to my github, where you can find the code that is causing this problem.

PC1 - Jetson AGX Xavier with ubuntu 18 and Nvidia Volta GPU.

PC2 - Lenovo ideapad with Ubuntu 18 and Nvidia GeForce mx150.

/************************************/

New edit: single-threaded version. It's the same thing -> nothing changes.
Here is what my render loop looks like:

```
versor rollQuat, pitchQuat, yawQuat;
glm_quat_identity(rollQuat);
glm_quat_identity(yawQuat);
glm_quat_identity(pitchQuat);
float yaw, pitch, roll;
yaw = 180;
pitch = 0;
roll = 0;
float yawd = 1;
float pitchd = 1;
float rolld = -1;

while (!EXIT){ // render loop
    processInput(window);
    roll += rolld;
    if (roll >= 50 || roll <=-50) rolld = -rolld;
    if (pitch >= 50 || pitch <=-50) pitchd = -pitchd;
    if (yaw >= 50 || yaw <=-50) yawd = -yawd;
    glm_quatv(pitchQuat, my_radians(pitch), (vec3){1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});
    glm_quatv(yawQuat, my_radians(yaw), (vec3){0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f});
    glm_quatv(rollQuat, my_radians(roll), (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});
    glm_quat_mul(yawQuat, pitchQuat, cam.resultQuat);
    glm_quat_mul(cam.resultQuat, rollQuat, cam.resultQuat);
    usleep(15000);
    // render
    my_clear_color_buffer(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    my_clear_buffer(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // generate projection matrix
    glm_perspective(cam.fov, (GLfloat)SCR_WIDTH / (GLfloat)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.01f, 100.0f, proj); // zoom

    // generate view matrix
    glm_quat_look(cam.cameraPos, cam.resultQuat, view);

    // send MVP matrices to vertex shader
    my_send_shander_4x4_matrix(modelLoc, 1, &model[0][0]); 
    my_send_shander_4x4_matrix(viewLoc, 1, &view[0][0]); 
    my_send_shander_4x4_matrix(projLoc, 1, &proj[0][0]);  
           
    my_bind_texture(textures[0]); 
    my_bind_vertex_object_and_draw_it(VAOs[0], GL_TRIANGLES, myWin.numTriangles);
    
        
    // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events
    my_swap_buffers(window);
    my_pool_events();
}
```

/************************************/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your loop never calls any rendering code? Why does the method return a void pointer?

Comment: I didn't provide render code here, just this, take a look at main.c at my github. Yeah, it's because I'm running that function in a thread.

Comment: If you are running the update in another thread than the rendering, then where is the synchronization between the two threads?

Comment: Well, since there is 15ms sleep in while loop. It's very unlikely that something like that causes the problem.

Comment: If you are sure about this, then write a minimal example that does not use a thread. Then include this example directly in your question. If the behavior does not persist without a thread, then we at least know where not to look.

Comment: I will do that first thing tomorrow because I don't have access to other computer at the moment.

Comment: I edited the question. Multithreading is not the problem.